# Добавление столбца в таблицу (ibexpert/ sql)

Tags: sql, firebase

Помогите пожалуйста к моему запросу:

```
select product.name, postavka.name,prixod.date_prix, prixod.kol

from prixod prixod

inner JOIN product product ON prixod.p_id = product.id

inner join postavka postavka ON prixod.post_id = postavka.id
```

добавить ещё один столбик с единицей измерения продуктов.

Этот столбик находится в таблице EI.NAME или в PRODUCT.EI.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]